# google API to get floor location name

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which I am getting the list of places near by the user. For that, i am using below Google Places API.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=latitude,Longitude&radius=10000&types=store&hasNextPage=true&nextPage()=true&sensor=false&key=Google_Map_key

do I get the indoor floor map locations accordingly using this API?